# What's a quick and dirty way to dynamically resolve a local host name on Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, dns, hostname

I have a web service running locally which, in the dev environment, has a dynamic IP address each time it runs. Annoyingly, I have to look up its IP each time and re-navigate to `http://$IP/foo`

I would like to be able to navigate to `http://my_service/foo` and have a script, say `/home/me/find_ip.sh` which will print the fresh IP of my service and have the name `my_service` resolve to the output of `find_ip.sh` each time it is requested.

Can I do this without setting up a full DNS server locally?

Is there a quick and dirty hack?

Comment: If your service is running locally, why does it have a dynamic IP address, and not 127.0.0.1? If it indeed does, can you get a notification when it starts (or wrap the start in a script)?

Comment: It's a development environment. Multiple versions of a service can be running, and port ranges are scarce and have to be re-used.

Comment: So you really want a redirection of a domain name to some specific port on localhost? (Note that `http://my_service/foo` will always use port 80, no matter which IP it uses). If yes, please update the question.

Comment: "I have a web service running locally" - what exactly do you mean by saying **locally**? On the **localhost** (aka 127.0.0.1) or in the **local network**?

Comment: It is running in a Docker container on the local machine.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to add `my_service` to `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost my_service
```

or

```
127.0.1.1 my_service
```

Another solution could be to [add virtual network interface like](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127863/virtual-always-connected-network-interface-with-static-ip).

**EDIT #1:**

A quick and dirty trick to make `my_service` work locally without DNS server is to modify `/etc/hosts`.

- Create `/home/me/find_ip.sh`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

FILE_OLD_IP=/tmp/ip.txt
OLD_IP='0.0.0.0'
NEW_IP=`ip route get 1 | awk '{print $NF;exit}'`

if [ -f "$FILE_OLD_IP" ]; then
        OLD_IP=`cat $FILE_OLD_IP`
fi


if [ $NEW_IP != $OLD_IP ]; then
    sed -i "s/.*my_service/$NEW_IP\tmy_service/" /etc/hosts
    echo $NEW_IP > $FILE_OLD_IP
    logger "NEW_IP: $NEW_IP"
else
    logger "CURRENT_IP: $NEW_IP"
fi
exit 0
```

- Schedule cron job `sudo crontabe -e`:

```
*/1 *  * * *   /home/me/find_ip.sh
```

Comment: It's not running on 127.0.0.1, it's a dynamic IP.